# Javascript Flashcard Studying App

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

Hello everyone I’m trying to create a simple studying app that work sort of like flash cards for studying. So the front side of the card it would have the question and on the back side the answer but digitally. I’m doing this all in JavaScript and plan to use HTML and CSS for the UI because it’s  all I know, I’m very new to coding. This is what I have so far

```
//User creates math object to study math
var mathObj = {
    "1+1": 2,
    "1+2": 3
}

//User creates Spanish object to study Spanish
var SpanishObj = {
    "Amigo": "Friend",
    "Agua": "Water"
}

//Function that is used to add key value pairs to a object
function addKeyVal(obj, key, val){
    obj[key] = val;
}

addKeyVal(mathObj,"1+3", 4);

//Function that tests the user
function testUser(obj){

objKeys = Object.keys(obj);
answer = obj[objKeys[2]];

var userResponse = prompt(objKeys[2]);

    if ( userResponse == answer) {
        alert("Correct");
    } else{
        alert("Incorrect");
    };
};

testUser(mathObj);
```

My first question is am I going about this correctly? That is should I be using objects instead of a key value pair array(just found out about these)? To help provide a clearer answer a key feature I want to add in the future is for the user to be able to randomize the order in which they receive questions. Final question is how can I have the user create their own Objects/Arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with adding from the page (and some more):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>


  <ul id="tests"></ul>

  <button id="btn-add">Add test</button>
  <button id="btn-save">Save tests</button>
  <!-- <button id="btn-load">Load tests</button> -->
  <button id="btn-clear">Clear storage</button>

  <div id="div-result"></div>
  <div id="div-total"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

(function ( document, window ) {

  var result = document.getElementById('div-result')
    , total = document.getElementById('div-total');

  // default object for a flash-card library
  function fc() {
    this.cards = {};
  }

  // clean input from tabs, spaces, uppercases
  fc.prototype.simplify = function ( val ) {
    if ( val !== null ) {
      return val.toLowerCase().trim();
    }
    return null;
  }

  // add to library an item
  fc.prototype.add = function ( key, val) {
    key = this.simplify( key );
    val = this.simplify( val );
    if ( key !== null && val !== null ) {
      this.cards[key] = val;
    }
  }

  // check the right value for the key
  fc.prototype.check = function ( key, val ) {
    key = this.simplify( key );
    val = this.simplify( val );

    if ( this.cards.hasOwnProperty( key ) && this.cards[ key ] === val ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  // test all values in order
  fc.prototype.start = function () {
    var rights = 0
      , wrongs = 0;

    result.innerHTML = '';
    total.innerHTML = '';

    for (var i in this.cards) {
      var guess = prompt('and a Spanish word for "' + i + '"' );
      if ( this.check( i, guess ) ) {
        result.innerHTML += 'Right: ' + i + ' &rarr; ' + this.cards[ i ];
        rights++;
      } else {
        result.innerHTML += 'Wrong: ' + guess + ', ' + i + ' &rarr; ' + this.cards[ i ];
        wrongs++;
      }
      result.innerHTML += '<br>';
    }
    total.innerHTML = 'Right answers: ' + rights + '<br>Wrong answers: ' +  wrongs ;
  }









  var app = ( function ( document, window ) {
    // declare some references, variables    
    var tests =  {}
      , el = document.getElementById('tests');

     function addTest () {
      var name = prompt('test name?');
      if ( name !== null ) {
        tests[ name ] = new fc();
        render();
      }
    }

    // register some events
    function registerEvents () {
      document.getElementById('btn-add').addEventListener( 'click', addTest, false );
      document.getElementById('btn-save').addEventListener( 'click', save, false );
      // document.getElementById('btn-load').addEventListener( 'click', load, false );
      document.getElementById('btn-clear').addEventListener( 'click', clear, false );
    }

    // render function
    function render () {
      var li = undefined
        , linkAdd = undefined
        , linkStart = undefined
        , docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

      // clear the dom
      while (el.firstChild) {
          el.removeChild( el.firstChild );
      };
      el.innerHTML = '';

      for ( var i in tests) {
        li = document.createElement( 'li' );
        li.innerHTML = i; // test name

        li.appendChild( document.createTextNode(' -> ') );

        // btn start test
        btnStart = document.createElement( 'button' );
        btnStart.setAttribute('data', i );

        btnStart.addEventListener( 'click', function( e ){
          var my = this.getAttribute( 'data');
          tests[ my ].start();
        }, false );

        btnStart.textContent = 'Start test';
        li.appendChild( btnStart );

        // btn add item to the test
        btnAdd = document.createElement( 'button' );
        btnAdd.setAttribute('data', i );

        btnAdd.addEventListener( 'click', function( e ){
          var my = this.getAttribute( 'data');
          tests[ my ].add( prompt( 'key' ), prompt( 'value' ));
        }, false );

        btnAdd.textContent = 'Add item';
        li.appendChild( btnAdd );

        // btn remove test
        btnRemove = document.createElement( 'button' );
        btnRemove.setAttribute('data', i );

        btnRemove.addEventListener( 'click', function( e ){
          var my = this.getAttribute( 'data');
          delete tests[ my ];
          render();
        }, false );

        btnRemove.textContent = 'Remove test';
        li.appendChild( btnRemove );

        docFrag.appendChild( li );
      };

      el.appendChild( docFrag );
    }

    // save tests to localstorage
    function save () {
      var data = JSON.stringify( tests );
      console.log( data );
      localStorage.setItem( 'tests', data );
    }

    // load tests form localstorage
    function load () {
      var saved = localStorage[ 'tests' ] || false;
      if ( saved ) {
        var data = undefined;
        data = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'tests' ) );
        console.log( data );

        // initialize test objects with loaded data
        for( var i in data ) {
          tests[ i ] = new fc();
          for ( var j in data[ i ] ) {
            tests[ i ][ j ] = data[ i ][ j ];
          }
        }
        render();
      } 
    }

    function clear () {
      localStorage.clear();
      tests = [];
      render();
    }

    // initialisation part
    registerEvents();
    load();

  } ) ( document, window );
} ) ( document, window );
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

i would make this way, though `alert` as a feedback is a terrible solution (very annoying), try to give it in html or use `console.log()`:

```
// default object for a flash-card library
function fc () {
  this.cards = {};
}

// clean input from tabs, spaces, upper-cases
// you can add functionality to make it better
fc.prototype.simplify = function ( val ) {
  return val.toLowerCase().trim();
}

// add to library an item
fc.prototype.add = function ( key, val ) {
  key = this.simplify( key );
  val = this.simplify( val );
  this.cards[ key ] = val;
}

// check the right value for the key
fc.prototype.check = function ( key, val ) {
  key = this.simplify( key );
  val = this.simplify( val );

  if ( this.cards.hasOwnProperty( key ) && this.cards[ key ] === val ) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

// test all values in order
fc.prototype.test = function () {
  for (var key in this.cards) {
    var guess = prompt('and a Spanish word for "' + key + '"' );
    if ( this.check( key, guess ) ) {
      alert( 'right' ); // console.log( 'right' )
    } else {
      alert( 'wrong' ); // console.log( 'wrong' )
    }
  }
}



// making a spanish cards stack
var spanish = new fc();

// adding cards
spanish.add( 'Friend', 'Amigo' );
spanish.add( 'Water', 'Agua' );


// starting the test
spanish.test();
```

Comment: Thanks alot Nik your way of adding keys and values and check solution are way better than mine. Now my only remaining question is how can I get the user to create the new cards via HTML would I just map a html element to onclick ="fc(this)" for the user to create a new object of their own making if they want to study a unique object of their own.

Comment: added below. you can do it this way(not fc(this) - cause that means nothing), but it is better to separate js from html as much as you can